# Как при клике на чекбокс получить его значение и записать в скрытое поле?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрытое поле с value="0".
При клике на чекбокс нужно записать в скрытое поле значение "1",
при повторном клике вернуть скрытому полю "0".
Как подобное можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C JQuery:**

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
 if ($(".skritoe-pole").attr("value")==0){
  $(".skritoe-pole").attr("value",1); 
 } else {
  $(".skritoe-pole").attr("value",0); 
 }
});
```

Для пущей уверенности в сравнении хорошо бы функцию parseInt() использовать. Можно, конечно, переписать и без JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

```
HTML:
<input type=hidden id='hiddenvalue' value=0 />
<input type=checkbox id='check1' onChange='ChangeValue("hiddenvalue","check1")' />

Javascript:
function ChangeValue(targ,dest){
if (document.getElementById(dest).checked){
    document.getElementById(targ).value = 1;
}else{
    document.getElementById(targ).value = 0;
}
}

`
```

Comment: Одно непонятно, зачем так делать надо было? При отправке формы и так будет известно, стоит галочка или нет. Использования значения скрытого элемента - лишний код, имхо.